# Easing animateMotion in SVG

Tags: animation, svg

I want to apply an easing to an animateMotion tag.

I'm confused about which attributes are relevant to animate a shape: if I understood well *calcMode="spline"* is required, along with the definition of *keyTimes* and *keySplines*; but what about the use of *keySplines* and *values*?

However, I tried to insert timings into my animation, but something went wrong:

```
        <g style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(180deg);">
          <path id="verticalMotionPath" d="m 100,100 0, 50" stroke-width="5px" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
            <animateMotion dur="0.2s" repeatCount="once" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keyPoints="0.25;0.50;0.75;1" keyTimes="0;0.25;0.75;1">
              <mpath xlink:href="#verticalMotionPath"/>
            </animateMotion>
          </circle>
        </g>
```

My aim would be to apply to [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/fillotassi/by3Lxf0h/15/) timings to draw from tools like [this one](http://franzheidl.github.io/keysplines/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying `calcMode="spline"`, but you haven't provided a `keySplines` attribute.

The value for `keySplines` can just be copied from your spline editing tool.

```
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
  <animateMotion dur="2.2s" repeatCount="once" fill="freeze"
                 calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.9 0.1">
    <mpath xlink:href="#verticalMotionPath"/>
  </animateMotion>
</circle>
```

Full demo (I've slowed down the animation so you can see it is working).

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <body>
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background:aquamarine">
        <style>
        path {
          animation-name:animateDash;
          animation-duration:5s;
          animation-iteration-count:once;
          animation-fill-mode:forwards;
        }
        @keyframes animateDash {
          from{stroke-dasharray:0,2305}
          to  {stroke-dasharray:2305,0}
        }
        </style>

        <g style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(180deg);">
          <path id="verticalMotionPath" d="m 100,100 0, 50" stroke-width="5px" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
            <animateMotion dur="2.2s" repeatCount="once" fill="freeze"
                           calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.9 0.1">
              <mpath xlink:href="#verticalMotionPath"/>
            </animateMotion>
          </circle>
        </g>

        <g style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(60deg);">
          <path id="verticalMotionPath" d="m 100,100 0, 50" stroke-width="5px" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
            <animateMotion dur="0.2s" repeatCount="once" fill="freeze">
              <mpath xlink:href="#verticalMotionPath"/>
            </animateMotion>
          </circle>
        </g>

        <g style="transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(-60deg);">
          <path id="verticalMotionPath" d="m 100,100 0, 50" stroke-width="5px" stroke="blue" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
            <animateMotion dur="0.2s" repeatCount="once" fill="freeze">
              <mpath xlink:href="#verticalMotionPath"/>
            </animateMotion>
          </circle>
        </g>

    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't understand well what's keyTimes for

Comment: `keyTimes` just sets specific times that an object has to be at a certain point in the animation. In this case 0 means start, and 1 means end.  That's all you need for this animation. But if you had a more complicated motion path, you might want to set multile keyTimes so that (for instance) it went slow for the first third of the time and fast for the next third, and then slow again.  But if you do that, you would need to add more spline definitions to `keySplines`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it although I don't use `animateMotion`.

Since your path is made up of lines you can define the values for `<animateTransform>` like this:

```
Your path's          d="M100, 100 L100, 47 146, 73"
the animation's  values="100, 100; 100, 47;146, 73"
```

This is a working example:

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="background:aquamarine">

        <path id="theMotionPath" d="M100, 100 L100, 47 146, 73" stroke-width="5px" stroke="antiquewhite" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
  
  <circle r="5" >   
     <animateTransform 
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="100,100; 100,47; 146,73" 
        keySplines= ".5 0 .5 1; 0 .75 .25 1";
        calcMode="spline" 
        dur="4s" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>

</svg>
```

The `keySplines` length must be equal to the length of the values - 1. In this case values.length = 3 thus keySplines.length = 2, i.e: the movement from the first to the second value is defined by the first key spline; the movement from the second to the third value is defined by the second key spline. Every value of the `keySplines` is defining the 2 control points of a Bézier curve.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this way of doing

If I understand well, you use _values_ to define shape's coordinates and _keySplines_ the timing; and the latter uses four numbers for each movement.

Comment: Yes. The 4 numbers are defining the 2 control points of a cubic Bézier: x1 y1 x2 y2